# Is there an equivalent to Visual SourceSafe's Shadow Directories in other VCS?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial, visual-sourcesafe

I have been asked to save the current versions of all files in all repositories on our Subversion server to a network drive. 
This is in addition to our backups of the repositories themselves.

Visual SourceSafe did this automatically by means of shadow folders.

Is there a way to accomplish this for a Subversion repository?

Is there an equivalent to shadow folders in any of the other current or popular VCS solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to say that I've forgotten how SourceSafe works, but Subversion has an export feature that will copy the current version of all files. You can also set up commit hooks that will perform tasks whenever someone commits changes.